# CMake target_include_directories and target_compile_definitions alternative

Tags: c++, cmake

CMake 2.8.11 introduces `target_include_directories` and `target_compile_definitions`. However some of the devices I am working one has 2.8.9. And I don't want to compile and build latest CMake there. So what is the alternative that I can use conditionally for those devices ?

How to check whether this cmake have `target_include_directories` or not from inside the CMakeLists.txt ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to get this functionality on earlier CMake versions, as the respective target properties that they are based on (`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`) are missing.

This is crucial as CMake uses these target properties to automatically propagate public and interface fields to dependent targets. Emulating this behavior from CMake code is rather difficult. For an in-house project we built a system that does just this a couple of years back before CMake supported it. This basically requires writing your own replacement functions for `add_library` and `add_executable` that handle the propagation in the background through user defined properties. All targets in the system then must use the replacement functions instead of the original CMake ones for the system to work. I would *strongly* recommend reconsidering your CMake upgrade policies before going for this option though.

The quickest way to check whether you can use these functions is by doing a [`cmake_minimum_required`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) (which you anyway should always do for all projects). If you want to make use of the commands, simply require at least 2.8.11. If you cannot make that requirement, use of the functions is out of the question in the first place and you will need to come up with an alternative. In which case it does not make much sense to check for their existence to begin with.

Comment: *"The quickest way to check whether you can use these functions is by doing a cmake_minimum_required..."* - that does *not* appear to be the case. When `target_include_directories` crept into our project with a 2.8.5 minimum, Cmake was happy to allow it to pass without even a warning.

Comment: @jww Yes, unfortunately it only works the other way around: *You* have to ensure that you only use commands that are covered by the specified minimum version. CMake will then complain when trying to run the scripts with an older version. CMake _won't_ warn if you use a command that is available on the CMake version you are currently running, but not on the minimum required version. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

ComicSansMS is correct about emulation not being possible prior to 2.8.11.

You can use

```
if (COMMAND target_include_directories)
endif()
```

or

```
if (COMMAND target_include_directories AND COMMAND target_compile_definitions)
endif()
```

as your test of whether the commands are available.

Answer (score -1):

> How to check whether this cmake have target_include_directories or not from inside the CMakeLists.txt ?

```
if (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
  target_include_directories(...)
else()
  # Not available
endif()
```